# How to model left-censored and right-truncated data on Stata?

Tags: stata, censoring, truncation

I have data that is left-censored and right-truncated.

I'd like to run a `tobit` or `truncreg`. Although, using `tobit`on `Stata` takes account both sides are censored or only one side is censored. Using `truncreg` takes account both sides are truncated or only one side is truncated.

Is there a way to deal with a data which is censored and truncated on `Stata`?

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you edit your question to remove the "in Stata" part (though you could specify a preference for that) in favor of more software-agnostic solution. It would also be helpful if you gave examples of the sort of data that you have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited substantially to reflect helpful suggestions.**

Take a look at David Roodman's command `cmp`, which is described in the Stata Journal article [here](https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/180074/2/sjart_st0224.pdf?ref=driverlayer.com/web) (though many features have been added since that came out).

I believe this would estimate a model in which the latent dependent variable is first truncated and then passes through a censoring process:

```
. webuse laborsup, clear

. sum fem_inc, detail // minimum female income is 10

                        Female income
-------------------------------------------------------------
      Percentiles      Smallest
 1%           10             10
 5%           10             10
10%           10             10       Obs                 500
25%           10             10       Sum of Wgt.         500

50%           10                      Mean           18.12979
                        Largest       Std. Dev.      12.70491
75%     23.20812       65.20599
90%     37.00847       66.28354       Variance       161.4148
95%     46.02529       72.50031       Skewness       1.788829
99%     59.69054        84.6134       Kurtosis        6.06882

. 
. /* Left Censoring Only */
. tobit fem_inc kids male_educ, ll

Refining starting values:

Grid node 0:   log likelihood = -1324.0111

Fitting full model:

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1324.0111  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1214.6402  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -1191.8252  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -1188.6169  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -1188.5826  
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -1188.5826  

Tobit regression                                Number of obs     =        500
                                                   Uncensored     =        228
Limits: lower = 10                                 Left-censored  =        272
        upper = +inf                               Right-censored =          0

                                                LR chi2(2)        =      59.33
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1188.5826                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0244

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          kids |  -4.135792   .8287279    -4.99   0.000    -5.764026   -2.507558
     male_educ |  -2.553038   .4308611    -5.93   0.000    -3.399568   -1.706509
         _cons |   46.17639   5.368424     8.60   0.000     35.62884    56.72395
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 var(e.fem_inc)|   469.4704   48.96169                      382.4891    576.2321
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, $cmp_cont, $cmp_left)") qui

Fitting individual models as starting point for full model fit.
Note: For programming reasons, these initial estimates may deviate from your specification.
      For exact fits of each equation alone, run cmp separately on each.

Fitting constants-only model for LR test of overall model fit.

Fitting full model.

Mixed-process regression                        Number of obs     =        500
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      59.33
Log likelihood = -1188.5826                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
fem_inc      |
        kids |  -4.135794   .8287292    -4.99   0.000    -5.760073   -2.511514
   male_educ |   -2.55304   .4308618    -5.93   0.000    -3.397513   -1.708566
       _cons |    46.1764   5.368432     8.60   0.000     35.65447    56.69834
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsig_1 |   3.075804   .0521458    58.98   0.000       2.9736    3.178008
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sig_1 |    21.6673   1.129859                      19.56222     23.9989
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* Right Truncation Only */
. truncreg fem_inc kids male_educ, ul(55)
(note: 9 obs. truncated)

Fitting full model:

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1857.7549  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1857.7537  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -1857.7537  

Truncated regression
Limit:   lower =       -inf                     Number of obs =   =        491
         upper =         55                     Wald chi2(2)      =      43.90
Log likelihood = -1857.7537                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        kids |  -1.682383   .3556318    -4.73   0.000    -2.379408   -.9853573
   male_educ |  -.8728686   .1834869    -4.76   0.000    -1.232496   -.5132409
       _cons |   31.12295    2.38037    13.07   0.000     26.45751    35.78839
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /sigma |   10.66551   .3444767    30.96   0.000      9.99035    11.34067
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators($cmp_cont) qui

Fitting individual models as starting point for full model fit.
Note: For programming reasons, these initial estimates may deviate from your specification.
      For exact fits of each equation alone, run cmp separately on each.

Fitting constants-only model for LR test of overall model fit.

Fitting full model.

Mixed-process regression                        Number of obs     =        491
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      42.14
Log likelihood = -1857.7537                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
fem_inc      |
        kids |  -1.682383   .3556318    -4.73   0.000    -2.379408   -.9853573
   male_educ |  -.8728686   .1834869    -4.76   0.000    -1.232496   -.5132409
       _cons |   31.12295   2.380369    13.07   0.000     26.45751    35.78839
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsig_1 |   2.367015   .0322982    73.29   0.000     2.303712    2.430319
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sig_1 |   10.66551   .3444767                      10.01128     11.3625
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* Both Censoring and Truncation */
. cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, $cmp_cont, $cmp_left)") qui

Fitting individual models as starting point for full model fit.
Note: For programming reasons, these initial estimates may deviate from your specification.
      For exact fits of each equation alone, run cmp separately on each.

Fitting constants-only model for LR test of overall model fit.

Fitting full model.

Mixed-process regression                        Number of obs     =        491
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      51.18
Log likelihood = -1118.6343                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
fem_inc      |
        kids |  -4.367595   .9732673    -4.49   0.000    -6.275164   -2.460026
   male_educ |  -2.605114   .5150163    -5.06   0.000    -3.614527   -1.595701
       _cons |   47.26099   6.615904     7.14   0.000     34.29406    60.22793
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsig_1 |    3.10493   .0756042    41.07   0.000     2.956748    3.253111
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sig_1 |   22.30766   1.686552                      19.23532    25.87071
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, cond(fem_inc > 55, $cmp_trunc, $cm
> p_cont), $cmp_left)") qui // deprecated way

Fitting individual models as starting point for full model fit.
Note: For programming reasons, these initial estimates may deviate from your specification.
      For exact fits of each equation alone, run cmp separately on each.

Fitting constants-only model for LR test of overall model fit.

Fitting full model.

Mixed-process regression                        Number of obs     =        491
                                                LR chi2(2)        =      51.18
Log likelihood = -1118.6343                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     fem_inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
fem_inc      |
        kids |  -4.367595   .9732673    -4.49   0.000    -6.275164   -2.460026
   male_educ |  -2.605114   .5150163    -5.06   0.000    -3.614527   -1.595701
       _cons |   47.26099   6.615904     7.14   0.000     34.29406    60.22793
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsig_1 |    3.10493   .0756042    41.07   0.000     2.956748    3.253111
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sig_1 |   22.30766   1.686552                      19.23532    25.87071
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Code:**

```
webuse laborsup, clear
sum fem_inc, detail // minimum female income is 10

/* Left Censoring Only */
tobit fem_inc kids male_educ, ll
cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, $cmp_cont, $cmp_left)") qui

/* Right Truncation Only */
truncreg fem_inc kids male_educ, ul(55)
cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators($cmp_cont) qui

/* Both Censoring and Truncation */
cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, $cmp_cont, $cmp_left)") qui
cmp (fem_inc = kids male_educ, truncpoints(. 55)), indicators("cond(fem_inc>10, cond(fem_inc > 55, $cmp_trunc, $cmp_cont), $cmp_left)") qui // deprecated way
```

Comment: Your proposal involves censored data on both sides. What if the right-side of the data distribution is truncated instead and censored on the left-side of the distribution?